# Incorrect report descriptor and report data structure?

Tags: c++, c, windows, device-driver, hid

I am working on a HID report descriptor which I am using by modifying the sample code here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WudfVhidmini-Sample-b304f83a/sourcecode?fileId=42918&pathId=205101617 (the link opens the queue.cpp file which is where most of my read/write code for the driver is and the default hid report descriptor). My updated report descriptor I have so far in my driver is (as of 5/11/2015):

```
  HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR           G_DefaultReportDescriptor[] = {
0x06, 0x00,0xFF,     // (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF00 Vendor-defined
0x09, 0x01,       // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001
0xA1, 0x01,        //(MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0xFF000001: Page=Vendor-defined, Usage=, Type=)
0x85, 0x0F,         // (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x0F (15)
0x09, 0x01,         // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001
0x15, 0x00,        //  (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0
0x26, 0xFF,0x00,      //  (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)
0x75, 0x08,          //(GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
0x96, 0x09, 0x00,        //(GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0009 (9) Number of fields
0xB1, 0x00,         // (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000000 (9 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
0x09, 0x01,         // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001
0x96, 0x01, 0x00,       // (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0001 (1) Number of fields
0x81, 0x00,        //  (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000000 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=Ignored 0=Ignored 0=PrefState 0=NoNull
0x09, 0x01,          //(LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001
0x96, 0x07, 0x00,       // (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0007 (7) Number of fields
0x91, 0x00,        //  (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000000 (7 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
0xC0,          // (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
0x05, 0x01,       // (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page
0x09, 0x02,       // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010002 Mouse (CA=Application Collection)
0xA1, 0x01,       // (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010002: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Mouse, Type=CA)
0x09, 0x01,       // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (CP=Physical Collection)
0xA1, 0x02,       // (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=CP) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CL (Logical)
0x05, 0x0A,       // (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page
0x09, 0x01,       // (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000A0001 Instance 1 (UM=Usage Modifier)
0x85, 0x01,       // (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1)
0xA1, 0x00,      //  (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x000A0001: Page=Ordinal Page, Usage=Instance 1, Type=UM) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical)
0x05, 0x09,      //    (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page
0x19, 0x01,      // (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x29, 0x03,      //  (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x15, 0x00,     //  (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0
0x25, 0x01,     //  (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
0x75, 0x01,     //   (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x03,      //  (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
0x81, 0x02,        // (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
0x95, 0x05,      //   (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields
0x81, 0x03,       //   (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1 = Constant 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x05, 0x01,       //       (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page
0x09, 0x30,       //       (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010030 X(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x09, 0x31,       //       (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010031 Y(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x15, 0x81,       //      (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,       //       (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)
0x75, 0x08,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x02,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields
0x81, 0x06,       //       (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 1 = Relative 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0xC0,  // END_COLLECTION     Physical
0x05, 0x0A,        //   (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page
0x09, 0x02,         //   (LOCAL)USAGE              0x000A0002 Instance 2 (UM = Usage Modifier)
0x85, 0x02,        //    (GLOBAL)REPORT_ID          0x02 (2)
0xA1, 0x00,        //    (MAIN)COLLECTION         0x00 Physical(Usage = 0x000A0002: Page = Ordinal Page, Usage = Instance 2, Type = UM) < --Warning: USAGE type should be CP(Physical)
0x05, 0x09,         //     (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page
0x19, 0x01,         //     (LOCAL)USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary / trigger(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x29, 0x03,         //     (LOCAL)USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x15, 0x00,       //       (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)
0x25, 0x01,       //       (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
0x75, 0x01,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x03,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
0x81, 0x02,       //       (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x95, 0x05,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields
0x81, 0x03,       //       (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1 = Constant 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x05, 0x01,       //       (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page
0x09, 0x30,       //       (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010030 X(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x09, 0x31,       //       (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010031 Y(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x15, 0x81,       //       (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,       //       (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)
0x75, 0x08,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x02,       //       (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields
0x81, 0x06,           //   (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 1 = Relative 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0xC0,       // END_COLLECTION     Physical
0x05, 0x0A,         //   (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page
0x09, 0x03,         //   (LOCAL)USAGE              0x000A0003 Instance 3 (UM = Usage Modifier)
0x85, 0x03,         //   (GLOBAL)REPORT_ID          0x03 (3)
0xA1, 0x00,           // (MAIN)COLLECTION         0x00 Physical(Usage = 0x000A0003: Page = Ordinal Page, Usage = Instance 3, Type = UM) < --Warning: USAGE type should be CP(Physical)
0x05, 0x09,           //   (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page
0x19, 0x01,           //   (LOCAL)USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary / trigger(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x29, 0x03,           //   (LOCAL)USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x15, 0x00,             // (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)
0x25, 0x01,             // (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
0x75, 0x01,             // (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x03,             // (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
0x81, 0x02,             // (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x95, 0x05,            //  (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields
0x81, 0x03,            //  (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1 = Constant 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x05, 0x01,            //  (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page
0x09, 0x30,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010030 X(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x09, 0x31,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010031 Y(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x15, 0x81,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)
0x75, 0x08,            //  (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x02,           //  (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields
0x81, 0x06,           //   (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 1 = Relative 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0xC0,        //   END_COLLECTION     Physical
0x05, 0x0A,           // (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page
0x09, 0x04,          //  (LOCAL)USAGE              0x000A0004 Instance 4 (UM = Usage Modifier)
0x85, 0x04,           // (GLOBAL)REPORT_ID          0x04 (4)
0xA1, 0x00,           // (MAIN)COLLECTION         0x00 Physical(Usage = 0x000A0004: Page = Ordinal Page, Usage = Instance 4, Type = UM) < --Warning: USAGE type should be CP(Physical)
0x05, 0x09,             // (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page
0x19, 0x01,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary / trigger(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x29, 0x03,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary(MULTI = Selector, On / Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
0x15, 0x00,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)
0x25, 0x01,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
0x75, 0x01,            //  (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x03,             // (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
0x81, 0x02,             // (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x95, 0x05,             // (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields
0x81, 0x03,            //  (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1 = Constant 1 = Variable 0 = Absolute 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0x05, 0x01,            //  (GLOBAL)USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page
0x09, 0x30,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010030 X(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x09, 0x31,            //  (LOCAL)USAGE              0x00010031 Y(DV = Dynamic Value)
0x15, 0x81,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)
0x25, 0x7F,            //  (GLOBAL)LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)
0x75, 0x08,            //  (GLOBAL)REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
0x95, 0x02,           //   (GLOBAL)REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields
0x81, 0x06,           //   (MAIN)INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0 = Data 1 = Variable 1 = Relative 0 = NoWrap 0 = Linear 0 = PrefState 0 = NoNull 0 = NonVolatile 0 = Bitmap
0xC0,        //   END_COLLECTION     Physical
0xC0,  // END_COLLECTION     Logical
0xC0,  // END_COLLECTION     Application
};
```

Here's the default report structure that came with the sample I am currently using (until I figure what I can change in it):

```
typedef struct _HIDMINI_INPUT_REPORT {

    UCHAR ReportId;   

    UCHAR Data; 

} HIDMINI_INPUT_REPORT, *PHIDMINI_INPUT_REPORT;

//
// output to device from system
//
typedef struct _HIDMINI_OUTPUT_REPORT {

    UCHAR ReportId;   

    UCHAR Data; 

    USHORT Pad1;

    ULONG Pad2;

} HIDMINI_OUTPUT_REPORT, *PHIDMINI_OUTPUT_REPORT;
```

My problem is 4 fold:

1. I need to pass data down from the control collection (the first collection before start of mouse devices comment is reached) for 4 mouse devices  down into the mouse collections. How would I write a report descriptor to do this or do I need code to also do this?
2. How would my report structure code look for reading/writing to the control structure from Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice?
3. Should I send each report descriptor like vmulti does except all in one loop?
4. How much of the above would be necessary if I was wanting to simulate/emulate mouse devices for multi-point mouse SDK or another multi mouse application? (sending input to the multi-mouse application)

Note: I plan on using the [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.aspx](http://%22https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.aspx%22) class functions to read/write from the 4 mouse devices defined above and that is why I am going to all the trouble to figure out this stuff. But the class on msdn clearly states I cannot write to the mouse devices directly. If it were so, I would have not been writing here. **In-case the question comes up: Yes, this is about injecting input into the mouse collections so I can get them to work with multi-mouse applications.** The above link to WudfVhidmin-Sample is not my code but the sample I am using to write my driver.

If I take out the part before the first end collection comment it creates three mouse devices but that's it.

Comment: here's the vmulti link to the source code online to see what I was talking about above: link here: https://code.google.com/p/vmulti/source/browse/test/testvmulti.c

Comment: P.S. this is the descriptor tool I am using that was recommended by some of the Microsoft WDK forum staff: http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage#HID Descriptor Tool.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to define a report descriptor to accommodate four physical mouse pointers (at least that is part of your question?). The HID report descriptor specification allows for the concept of "Instances", so I think trying something like the following report descriptor might be worth investigating. **I have no idea whether it would work in practice**, but it is based on a (rather flakey IMHO) example in "Appendix A.5 Multiple Instances of a Control" in the [HID Usage Tables 1.12 specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf).

As far as I can see there is no way to define an instance once and somehow generate four of them. You seem to have to duplicate the report descriptor for each instance.

Worth a shot anyway.

The following was produced by some code I wrote a while back called [hidrdd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/) to help me decode HID report descriptors:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
06 00FF      (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF00 Vendor-defined 
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0xFF000001: Page=Vendor-defined, Usage=, Type=)
85 0F          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x0F (15) 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001  
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0
26 FF00        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255) 
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field 
96 0900        (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0009 (9) Number of fields 
B1 00          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000000 (9 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001  
96 0100        (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0001 (1) Number of fields 
81 00          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000000 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=Ignored 0=Ignored 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001  
96 0700        (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0007 (7) Number of fields 
91 00          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000000 (7 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 02        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010002 Mouse (CA=Application Collection) 
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010002: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Mouse, Type=CA)
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (CP=Physical Collection) 
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=CP) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CL (Logical)
05 0A            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page 
09 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000A0001 Instance 1 (UM=Usage Modifier) 
85 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1) 
A1 00            (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x000A0001: Page=Ordinal Page, Usage=Instance 1, Type=UM) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical)
05 09              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
29 03              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
15 00              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0
25 01              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) 
75 01              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field 
95 03              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields 
81 02              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields 
81 03              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (DV=Dynamic Value) 
09 31              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 81              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127) 
25 7F              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127) 
75 08              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field 
95 02              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields 
81 06              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0               (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical
05 0A            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page 
09 02            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000A0002 Instance 2 (UM=Usage Modifier) 
85 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x02 (2) 
A1 00            (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x000A0002: Page=Ordinal Page, Usage=Instance 2, Type=UM) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical)
05 09              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
29 03              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
15 00              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) 
25 01              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) 
75 01              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field 
95 03              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields 
81 02              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields 
81 03              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (DV=Dynamic Value) 
09 31              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 81              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127) 
25 7F              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127) 
75 08              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field 
95 02              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields 
81 06              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0               (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical
05 0A            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page 
09 03            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000A0003 Instance 3 (UM=Usage Modifier) 
85 03            (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x03 (3) 
A1 00            (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x000A0003: Page=Ordinal Page, Usage=Instance 3, Type=UM) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical)
05 09              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
29 03              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
15 00              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) 
25 01              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) 
75 01              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field 
95 03              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields 
81 02              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields 
81 03              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (DV=Dynamic Value) 
09 31              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 81              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127) 
25 7F              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127) 
75 08              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field 
95 02              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields 
81 06              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0               (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical
05 0A            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000A Ordinal Page 
09 04            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000A0004 Instance 4 (UM=Usage Modifier) 
85 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x04 (4) 
A1 00            (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x000A0004: Page=Ordinal Page, Usage=Instance 4, Type=UM) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical)
05 09              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
29 03              (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
15 00              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) 
25 01              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) 
75 01              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field 
95 03              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields 
81 02              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields 
81 03              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01              (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (DV=Dynamic Value) 
09 31              (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 81              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127) 
25 7F              (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127) 
75 08              (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field 
95 02              (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields 
81 06              (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0               (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
```

This should correspond to C declarations like:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined featureReport 0F (Device <-> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x0F (15)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined[9];                     // Value = 0 to 255
} featureReport0F_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined inputReport 0F (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x0F (15)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined;                        // Value = 0 to 255
} inputReport0F_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined outputReport 0F (Device <-- Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x0F (15)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined[7];                     // Value = 0 to 255
} outputReport0F_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: Mouse Pointer Instance1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance1Button1 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance1Button2 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance1Button3 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance1X;                // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance1Y;                // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport01_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport 02 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
                                                     // Collection: Mouse Pointer Instance2
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance2Button1 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance2Button2 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance2Button3 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance2X;                // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance2Y;                // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport02_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport 03 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x03 (3)
                                                     // Collection: Mouse Pointer Instance3
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance3Button1 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance3Button2 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance3Button3 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance3X;                // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance3Y;                // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport03_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport 04 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x04 (4)
                                                     // Collection: Mouse Pointer Instance4
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance4Button1 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance4Button2 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerInstance4Button3 : 1;     // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance4X;                // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerInstance4Y;                // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport04_t;
```

Comment: thank you. I was trying to create the 4 mouse devices and have a control collection for each one or have a master control collection for sending data to/from 4 different mouse devices (I am needing to inject input though into the 4 lower mouse devices). Essentially, I use the windows.devices.humaninterface devices class which calls other win32 functions related to reading devices internally but it does not take a mouse device directly to read/write from. Note: I can successfully send input to the control collection and read it but not the mouse devices yet.

Comment: I will decode this and see what does and does not work and get back with you.

Comment: One more note: The reason for this is to emulate/simulated mouse devices but I need the control collection to pass data on down because win32 api's do not allow for this directly. I do not need the pointers because I am writing this code for combination with Multipoint mouse SDK and mouse mischief powerpoint add-on. I only need the drivers because I plan on combination with another device (Kinect, Smart boards, etc.).

Comment: Can you please add a driver side code sample of WriteOutputReport function in the first link listed in my post? (I'll update with what I have tommorow) I am working on the code but if you have an example of the output the input report would probably be much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows developer. I was interested in decoding HID report descriptors for a microcontroller protect a few years back and that's when I discovered how (hideously) complicated it was. When I finished the decoder I ran it against all the samples in the official spec ...  you'd be surprised how many of the examples were flaky. No wonder people have so much trouble with HID.

Comment: I was able to get a first try at it and it appears it creates separate mouse devices in device manager. So, that may allow me to write to them separately but I get a device cannot start error. I am guessing it has to do with the report descriptor being improper somewhere. Its so close though. I'll upload my driver code so far to prevent you from having to make major changes. P.S. I have a usage and usage page code what would they be in this instance, so I can read/write to the mouse devices?

Comment: here's a picture of what it looks like in device manager: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/649536. Here's a link to the full source code I have right now: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=28bae91ca075b1e5!4963&authkey=!AMHtpjiBgI0PfZA&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: You need to use bit field declarations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx for the mouse buttons and pad fields so that they match the report descriptor. You changed them to byte fields. The c structures must match the report descriptor.

Comment: Never mind, I get three mouse devices but they are not starting. Maybe, its something wrong with my driver code. Could it be the usage returned or the Report descriptor still?

Comment: I think I realized why it was not working your descriptor is too big and it is trying to truncate it. Do you have this in actual C? I am trying to convert it to C and having problems.

Comment: As I have already said, I'm not a Windows programmer,  but I can see a simple problem with your C definitions. The report descriptor type is declared as "typedef UCHAR HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR" ... so you must initialize the array with a sequence of UCHAR (that is, 8-bit values). So where, for example, you have coded "0x00FF", you need to code "0x00, 0xFF" instead (respecting the required little-endian byte order). Otherwise the compiler will silently truncate 0x00FF to a single byte with a value of 0xFF which will not be parsed correctly by the host.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. It thought maybe it might be something simple. Most of the time when I have a problem its a easily solvable one and I only missed something. In this case, I am out of my comfort zone but I like learning new things.

Comment: Here's a picture after I performed your last suggestion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/655724. I believe I am still missing something in my report descriptor. I posted the updated report descriptor above.

Comment: P.S. here's my full source code for download if you wish to look at it and see if theirs anything I am doing wrong: https://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/614518. I found that code sample in the documentation you posted. You can check my code but I have only made minor changes to accommodate your changes mentioned above in the answer.

Comment: what the heck I change it to one mouse device and the devices show up properly? Maybe its how you are ending the collections? You might need to clean up your answer a little and I think it will work. It seems something is missing or a end collection was not added.

Comment: After playing around with your answer it seems something is wrong with your data structure or I implemented it wrong. I cannot get data back but the data gets sent in an output report and vanishes. My guess is the data is never injected on the mouse device.